# IVideoWindow MessageDrain not working in VB?

Tags: vb.net, directshow

I have a VB application in which I'm displaying 2 video files using QuartzTypeLib. 
Now I'm trying to handle a click event and a double click event on each video.

The declaration of the `IVideoWindow` is :

`Public videowindow(0 To 1) As QuartzTypeLib.IVideoWindow`

And I set the owner and messagedrain like this:

```
 For i = 0 To 1


            videowindow(i).Owner = videolist(i).Handle.ToInt32
            videowindow(i).MessageDrain = videolist(i).Handle.ToInt32

  Next i
```

Where `videolist` is a list of panels.

I've create a click event for `videolist(0)` and `videolist(1)` but the events are not working ( nothing happens when I click the video ). Are there some additional steps to perform before handling the `IVideoWindow` events ?

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You should be able to use Spy++ utility to see if message are correctly forwarded to the target window. Once you make sure this happens, check your VB app window why this message is not handled correctly.

Comment: @RomanR. Thank you. I've searched on the internet and I've found that I not handle the click event correctly. For the click event, I simply generated a event on the panel, but from what I've read I saw that I need to override the `WndProc` method. Do you know how I can do that ?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?664069-Direct-Show-Click-Event) what you are looking for? Or if you need VB.NET sample, if it is even easier to google a suitable one.

Comment: That's exaclty what I need. In my case it's not working or I'm not processing the event correctly.